# Get form element value in IE and Edge without querySelector

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

Suppose I have one form, which contains two radio buttons with the same name "question1". There is another text input with name "question2". I want the most efficient way to check if both inputs are filled, so I need some code that can access the values of those inputs.

This line works for most of the browsers but the Microsoft ones because they have a stupid HTMLCollection layer:

```
var val1 = document.forms[0].elements['question1'].value // undefined in Microsoft;
var val2 = document.forms[0].elements['question2'].value // undefined in Microsoft;
```

With querySelector, I can do something like this which will work for Microsoft:

```
document.querySelector("form input[name='question1']:checked").value;
document.querySelector("form input[name='question2']").value;
```

Note that these two lines are different. I actually have tens of those questions so I prefer one piece of code that will work for all of them. Is there a Microsoft way that functions like the first section of the code?

**Clarification:**

I want to know if there is one line of code that will work for ANY type of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for IE:

```
var allElems = document.getElementsByTagName('question1');
for (i = 0; i < allElems.length; i++) {
    if (allElems[i].type == 'radio' && allElems[i].value !== ' ') {
        allElems[i].checked = true;
    }
}
```

for the rest:

```
   var elements = document.getElementsByName('question1');
     for (i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
     if(elements[i].value !== "") {
      elements[i].checked = true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not gonna work for radio buttons and checkboxes. For radio and checkbox type you usually only want whichever value is selected.

Comment: Ops I did not pay much attention to the question. I updated my answer.

Comment: Yeah thanks, but this is pretty straightforward loop solution. I am looking for something built-in the browser so it is more efficient.

Comment: oh I dont think you can find something browser build in